# Hibernate ManyToOne auto generated condition with AND instead of OR in WHERE

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a query looks like this :

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT l FROM Lesson l "
        + "LEFT JOIN l.adminPermissionSet ad "
        + "WHERE l.creatorId = :adminId OR ad.adminId = :adminId "
        + "AND ((:searchValue = '')"
        + "   OR (:searchValue <> '' "
        + "       AND (CONVERT(l.id, CHAR) LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchValue, '%') "
        + "           OR l.title LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchValue, '%') "
        + "           OR l.creator.empNm LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchValue, '%')"
        + "           OR l.creator.engNm LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchValue, '%'))"
        + "      )"
        + "    )")
Page<Lesson> findByAdmin(@Param("adminId") Long adminId, Pageable pageable, @Param("searchValue") String search);
```

Given the field `creator` in `Lesson` entity

```java
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "creator_id" , insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User creator;
```

The part `l.creator` triggers Hibernate to automatically adds this condition in the already existing `WHERE` clause. The `WHERE` clause then becomes (generated native mysql):

```sql
join user user6_ 
where
    lesson0_.creator_id=516
    and (
        lesson0_.creator_id=516
        or adminpermi2_.admin_id=516
    )
```

We can see that it automatically prepends `lesson0_.creator_id=516 and` in my `WHERE` clause. Is it possible to change it to `lesson0_.creator_id=516 or`?

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible. I assume that what you are seeing here is the join condition for joining the association `creator` due to the de-referencing in your HQL WHERE clause `l.creator.engNm`

Comment: Yes, your assumption is right. However, it's annoying to see that behavior of Hibernate. It always do that with an `AND` condition and in this case making the logic in the `WHERE` clause incorrect.

Comment: It's not incorrect, but just the semantics of the path navigation. If you need "optionality", then use `left join l.creator c` and use `c.id is null or ...` instead of `l.creator.empNm`